# How to find limits of integration of polar curves?

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates, area, curves

Right now I am working on a problem that involves finding the area enclosed by a single loop given the equation $r=4\cos(3\theta)$. I know that the cosine is bounded from zero to $\pi$, but when using a lower limit of $0$, and a upper limit of $\pi/3$, I get the wrong answer (the answer is $4\pi/3$).

Should I instead use zero to $2\pi/3$, since that would be a full period? I tried drawing the graph as well, but had no luck with that. What is the best way of finding the upper and lowers limits for these kind of problems?

Comment: "I tried drawing the graph as well, but had no luck with that" For this part, see [this online tool](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+r%3D4cos(3theta)), which might also make the mathematical answer to the rest of your question quite transparent.

Comment: Use limits of theta (T) from 0 to (pi/6), since 3T will have total limit from 0 to (pi/2).

Comment: Using those limits worked, but why are those the limits of integration. Why not -pi/6 to pi/6, since the given function would be zero there.

Answer (score 3):

It helps if you have an idea of the [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+r%3D4cos(3theta)), but even if you don't: it should be clear that at $\theta = 0$, you have $r(0) = 4$ so you're not at the beginning of a loop. A loop starts when $r=0$ and a single loop closes at the next root of $r(\theta)$.

The function $\cos x$ has a root at $-\tfrac{\pi}{2}$ and the next one is at $\tfrac{\pi}{2}$. For this polar curve $r = 4 \cos(3\theta)$, you get (with $x=3\theta$):
$$3\theta = \pm \frac{\pi}{2} \Rightarrow \theta = \pm \frac{\pi}{6}$$
so you go through exactly one loop if you let $\theta$ run from $-\tfrac{\pi}{6}$ to $\tfrac{\pi}{6}$. Using the formula for area:
$$\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} \tfrac{1}{2}r^2 \,\mbox{d}\theta \to
\int_{-\tfrac{\pi}{6}}^{\tfrac{\pi}{6}} \tfrac{1}{2}\left( 4 \cos(3\theta) \right)^2 \,\mbox{d}\theta = \cdots = \frac{4\pi}{3}$$
Note that because the function is even, it is slightly easier to (manually) calculate :
$$\color{blue}{2}\int_{\color{red}{0}}^{\tfrac{\pi}{6}} \tfrac{1}{2}\left( 4 \cos(3\theta) \right)^2 \,\mbox{d}\theta = \int_{0}^{\tfrac{\pi}{6}} \left( 4 \cos(3\theta) \right)^2 \,\mbox{d}\theta = \cdots = \frac{4\pi}{3}$$

Comment: That helps, thanks! When I integrate it though I am getting 8pi/3, not 4pi/3.

Comment: It's probably a mistake in your calculation, the answer is indeed $4\pi/3$.

Comment: Yes, I was not dividing by two when I needed to. I looked it over again, and got 4π/3.